# Why can't I use accented characters next to a word boundary?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, replace, diacritics

I'm trying to make a dynamic regex that matches a person's name. It works without problems on most names, until I ran into accented characters at the end of the name.

Example: Some Fancy Namé

The regex I've used so far is:

```
/\b(Fancy Namé|Namé)\b/i
```

Used like this:

```
"Goal: Some Fancy Namé. Awesome.".replace(/\b(Fancy Namé|Namé)\b/i, '<a href="#">$1</a>');
```

This simply won't match. If I replace the é with a e, it matches just fine.
If I try to match a name such as "Some Fancy Naméa", it works just fine.
If I remove the word last word boundary anchor, it works just fine.

Why doesn't the word boundary flag work here? Any suggestions on how I would get around this problem?

I have considered using something like this, but I'm not sure what the performance penalties would be like:

```
"Some fancy namé. Allow me to ellaborate.".replace(/([\s.,!?])(fancy namé|namé)([\s.,!?]|$)/g, '$1<a href="#">$2</a>$3')
```

Suggestions? Ideas?

Comment: i'm gonna guess that maybe é is not considered a word character (\w) ...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

JavaScript's regex implementation is not Unicode-aware. It only knows the ‘word characters’ in standard low-byte ASCII, which does not include `é` or any other accented or non-English letters.

Because `é` is not a word character to JS, `é` followed by a space can never be considered a word boundary. (It would match `\b` if used in the middle of a word, like `Namés`.)

> `/([\s.,!?])(fancy namé|namé)([\s.,!?]|$)/`

Yeah, that would be the usual workaround for JS (though probably with more punctuation characters). For other languages you'd generally use lookahead/lookbehind to avoid matching the pre and post boundary characters, but these are poorly supported/buggy in JS so best avoided.

Comment: That explains it. I ended up with the following:

/(\W|^)(fancy namé|namé)(\W|$)/ig

Which seems to fit my needs :-)

Answer (score 8):

Rob is correct. Quoted from the ECMAScript 3rd edition:

15.10.2.6 Assertion:

> The production *Assertion* `\b` evaluates by ...
>
> **2.** Call *IsWordChar(e−1)* and let *a* be the boolean result
>   **3.** Call *IsWordChar(e)* and let *b* be the boolean result

and

> The internal helper function *IsWordChar* ... performs the following:
>
> **3.** If *c* is one of the sixty-three characters in the table below, return **true**.
>
> ```
> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
> A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 _
> ```

Since `é` is not one of these 63 characters, the location between `é` and `a` will be considered a word boundary.

If you know the class of characters, you may use a negative look-forward assertion, e.g.

```
/(^|[^\wÀ-ÖØ-öø-ſ])(Fancy Namé|Namé)(?![\wÀ-ÖØ-öø-ſ])/
```

Answer (score 3):

### Know Your Boundaries

Unfortunately, even if and when Javascript should someday come to have full and proper support for Unicode, you will **still** have to be exquisitely careful with word boundaries. It’s easy to misunderstand what a `\b` really does.

Here is Perl code that explains what `\b` is really doing, which is true no matter whether your pattern engine has been BNM-upgraded yet:

```
  # if next is word char:
  #     then last isn't    word
  #     else last isn't nonword

    $word_boundary_before = qr{ (?(?=  \w ) (?<! \w ) | (?<! \W ) ) }x;

  # if last is word:
  #     then next isn't    word
  #     else next isn't nonword

    $word_boundary_after  = qr{ (?(?<= \w ) (?!  \w ) | (?!  \W ) ) }x;
```

The first is like a `\b` before something, and the second is like a `\b` after it.  The construct used is the regex “IF-THEN=ELSE” conditional, which is of the general form `(?(COND)THEN|ELSE)`.  Here I’m using a *COND* test that’s a lookahead in the first case but a lookahead in the second one.  The *THEN* and *ELSE* clauses in both cases are negated lookarounds so that they take the edge of the string into account.

I explain more about dealing with boundaries and Unicode in regular expressions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213800/is-there-something-like-a-counter-variable-in-regular-expression-replace/4214173#4214173).

### Unicode Property Support

The [current state of affairs in Javascript’s treatment of Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280712/javascript-unicode/280762#280762) *seems* to be that like Java, Javascript’s definitions of `\w` and such are still **crippled by being stuck back in the 1960s** world of ASCII. This is just a miserable situation, I admit.  Even Python, which is pretty conservative as these things go (for example, it doesn’t even support recursive regexes), *does* allow its definitions of `\w` and `\s` to work on Unicode correctly.  That’s the barest minimum level of functionality, really.

It is both better and worse in Javasscript. That’s bcecause you *can* use a few of the very most basic of Unicode properties in Javascript (or Java). It looks like you should be able to use the one- and two-character “General Category” Unicode properties. That means you should be able to use the short name versions from the first column below:

```
Short Name  Long Name
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 \pL        \p{Letter}
   \p{Lu}   \p{Uppercase_Letter}
   \p{Ll}   \p{Lowercase_Letter}
   \p{Lt}   \p{Titlecase_Letter}
   \p{Lm}   \p{Modifier_Letter}
   \p{Lo}   \p{Other_Letter}

Short Name  Long Name
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 \pM       \p{Mark}
   \p{Mn}  \p{Nonspacing_Mark}
   \p{Mc}  \p{Spacing_Mark}
   \p{Me}  \p{Enclosing_Mark}

Short Name  Long Name
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 \pN       \p{Number}
   \p{Nd}  \p{Decimal_Number},\p{Digit}
   \p{Nl}  \p{Letter_Number}
   \p{No}  \p{Other_Number}

Short Name  Long Name
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 \pP       \p{Punctuation}, \p{Punct})
   \p{Pc}  \p{Connector_Punctuation}
   \p{Pd}  \p{Dash_Punctuation}
   \p{Ps}  \p{Open_Punctuation}
   \p{Pe}  \p{Close_Punctuation}
   \p{Pi}  \p{Initial_Punctuation}
   \p{Pf}  \p{Final_Punctuation}
   \p{Po}  \p{Other_Punctuation}

Short Name  Long Name
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 \pS       \p{Symbol}
   \p{Sm}  \p{Math_Symbol}
   \p{Sc}  \p{Currency_Symbol}
   \p{Sk}  \p{Modifier_Symbol}
   \p{So}  \p{Other_Symbol}

Short Name  Long Name
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 \pZ       \p{Separator}
   \p{Zs}  \p{Space_Separator}
   \p{Zl}  \p{Line_Separator}
   \p{Zp}  \p{Paragraph_Separator}

Short Name  Long Name
¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯
 \pC       \p{Other}
   \p{Cc}  \p{Control}, \p{Cntrl}
   \p{Cf}  \p{Format}
   \p{Cs}  \p{Surrogate}
   \p{Co}  \p{Private_Use}
   \p{Cn}  \p{Unassigned}
```

You have to use the short names only in Java and Javascript, but Perl lets you use the long names too, which helps for legibilityl the 5.12 release of Perl supports about 3,000 Unicode properties. Python *still* doesn’t have any Unicode property support worth mentioning, and Ruby is just starting to get it in the 1.9 release. PCRE has some limited support, mostly like Java 1.7’s.

Java6 supports Unicode block properties, like `\p{InGeneralPunctuation}` or `\p{Block=GeneralPunctuation}`, and Java7 supports Unicode script properties, like `\p{IsHiragana}` or `\p{Script=Hiragana}`.

However, it still doesn’t support anything even close to the [full set of Unicode properties](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html), including near-critical ones like `\p⁠{WhiteSpace}`, `\p{Dash}`, and `\p{Quotation_Mark}`, let alone the other two-parters like `\p⁠{Line_Break=Alphabetic}`, `\p⁠{East_Asian_Width:Narrow}`, `\p⁠{Numeric_Value=1000}`, or `\p⁠⁠{Age:5.2}`.

The former set are pretty indispensable — *especially* given the lack of support for `\s` working right — and the latter set are pretty darned useful at times.

Something else that Java and Javascript doesn’t yet support is [user-defined character properties](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#User-Defined-Character-Properties). I use those quite a bit.  That way you can define things like `\p⁠{English::Vowel}` or `\p⁠{English::Consonant}`, which is quite handy.

If you’re interested in Unicode properties for regex work, tou might want to grab the *unitrio* suite of programs: [uniprops](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops),  [unichars](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars), and [uninames](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames).  Here’s a demo of each of those three:

```
$ uninames face
 ፦  4966  1366  ETHIOPIC PREFACE COLON
 ⁙  8281  2059  FIVE DOT PUNCTUATION
        = Greek pentonkion
        = quincunx
        x (die face-5 - 2684)
 ∯  8751  222F  SURFACE INTEGRAL
        # 222E 222E
 ☹  9785  2639 WHITE FROWNING FACE
 ☺  9786  263A WHITE SMILING FACE
        = have a nice day!
 ☻  9787  263B BLACK SMILING FACE
 ⚀  9856  2680 DIE FACE-1
 ⚁  9857  2681 DIE FACE-2
 ⚂  9858  2682 DIE FACE-3
 ⚃  9859  2683 DIE FACE-4
 ⚄  9860  2684 DIE FACE-5
 ⚅  9861  2685 DIE FACE-6
 ⾯  12207 2FAF KANGXI RADICAL FACE
        # 9762
 〠  12320 3020 POSTAL MARK FACE
 龜  64206 FACE CJK COMPATIBILITY IDEOGRAPH-FACE
        : 9F9C
```

FMTEYEWTK about Unicode properties:

```
$ uniprops -va LF 85 Greek:Sigma INFINITY BOM U+3000 U+12345

U+000A ‹U+000A› \N{ LINE FEED (LF) }:
    \s \v \R \pC \p{Cc}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{ASCII} \p{Assigned} \p{C} \p{Other} \p{Cc} \p{Cntrl} \p{Common} \p{Zyyy} \p{Control} \p{Pat_WS} \p{Pattern_White_Space} \p{PatWS} \p{PerlSpace} \p{PosixCntrl} \p{PosixSpace} \p{Space} \p{SpacePerl} \p{VertSpace} \p{White_Space} \p{WSpace}
    \p{Age:1.1} \p{Block=Basic_Latin} \p{Bidi_Class:B} \p{Bidi_Class=Paragraph_Separator} \p{Bidi_Class:Paragraph_Separator} \p{Bc=B} \p{Block:ASCII} \p{Block:Basic_Latin} \p{Blk=ASCII} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Script=Common} \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None} \p{East_Asian_Width=Neutral} \p{East_Asian_Width:Neutral} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:LF} \p{GCB=LF} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA}
       \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup} \p{Joining_Type:Non_Joining} \p{Jt=U} \p{Joining_Type:U} \p{Joining_Type=Non_Joining} \p{Line_Break:LF} \p{Line_Break=Line_Feed}
       \p{Line_Break:Line_Feed} \p{Lb=LF} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:1.1} \p{Age=1.1} \p{In=1.1} \p{Present_In:2.0} \p{In=2.0} \p{Present_In:2.1} \p{In=2.1} \p{Present_In:3.0} \p{In=3.0} \p{Present_In:3.1} \p{In=3.1}
       \p{Present_In:3.2} \p{In=3.2} \p{Present_In:4.0} \p{In=4.0} \p{Present_In:4.1} \p{In=4.1} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2} \p{Script:Common} \p{Sc=Zyyy} \p{Script:Zyyy} \p{Sentence_Break:LF} \p{SB=LF} \p{Word_Break:LF}
       \p{WB=LF}

U+0085 ‹U+0085› \N{ NEXT LINE (NEL) }:
    \s \v \R \pC \p{Cc}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Assigned} \p{InLatin1} \p{C} \p{Other} \p{Cc} \p{Cntrl} \p{Common} \p{Zyyy} \p{Control} \p{Pat_WS} \p{Pattern_White_Space} \p{PatWS} \p{Space} \p{SpacePerl} \p{VertSpace} \p{White_Space} \p{WSpace}
    \p{Age:1.1} \p{Bidi_Class:B} \p{Bidi_Class=Paragraph_Separator} \p{Bidi_Class:Paragraph_Separator} \p{Bc=B} \p{Block:Latin_1} \p{Block=Latin_1_Supplement} \p{Block:Latin_1_Supplement} \p{Blk=Latin1} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Script=Common} \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None} \p{East_Asian_Width=Neutral} \p{East_Asian_Width:Neutral} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:CN} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Control}
       \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Control} \p{GCB=CN} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup} \p{Joining_Type:Non_Joining} \p{Jt=U}
       \p{Joining_Type:U} \p{Joining_Type=Non_Joining} \p{Line_Break:Next_Line} \p{Lb=NL} \p{Line_Break:NL} \p{Line_Break=Next_Line} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:1.1} \p{Age=1.1} \p{In=1.1} \p{Present_In:2.0} \p{In=2.0}
       \p{Present_In:2.1} \p{In=2.1} \p{Present_In:3.0} \p{In=3.0} \p{Present_In:3.1} \p{In=3.1} \p{Present_In:3.2} \p{In=3.2} \p{Present_In:4.0} \p{In=4.0} \p{Present_In:4.1} \p{In=4.1} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2}
       \p{Script:Common} \p{Sc=Zyyy} \p{Script:Zyyy} \p{Sentence_Break:SE} \p{Sentence_Break=Sep} \p{Sentence_Break:Sep} \p{SB=SE} \p{Word_Break:Newline} \p{WB=NL} \p{Word_Break:NL} \p{Word_Break=Newline}

U+03A3 ‹Σ› \N{ GREEK CAPITAL LETTER SIGMA }:
    \w \pL} \p{LC} \p{L_} \p{L&} \p{Lu}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Alnum} \p{Alpha} \p{Alphabetic} \p{Assigned} \p{Greek} \p{Is_Greek} \p{InGreek} \p{Cased} \p{Cased_Letter} \p{LC} \p{Changes_When_Casefolded} \p{CWCF} \p{Changes_When_Casemapped} \p{CWCM} \p{Changes_When_Lowercased} \p{CWL} \p{Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded}
       \p{CWKCF} \p{Lu} \p{L} \p{Gr_Base} \p{Grapheme_Base} \p{Graph} \p{GrBase} \p{Grek} \p{Greek_And_Coptic} \p{ID_Continue} \p{IDC} \p{ID_Start} \p{IDS} \p{Letter} \p{L_} \p{Uppercase_Letter} \p{Print} \p{Upper} \p{Uppercase} \p{Word} \p{XID_Continue} \p{XIDC} \p{XID_Start}
       \p{XIDS}
    \p{Age:1.1} \p{Bidi_Class:L} \p{Bidi_Class=Left_To_Right} \p{Bidi_Class:Left_To_Right} \p{Bc=L} \p{Block:Greek} \p{Block=Greek_And_Coptic} \p{Block:Greek_And_Coptic} \p{Blk=Greek} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None} \p{East_Asian_Width:A} \p{East_Asian_Width=Ambiguous} \p{East_Asian_Width:Ambiguous} \p{Ea=A} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Other} \p{GCB=XX}
       \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other} \p{Script=Greek} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup}
       \p{Joining_Type:Non_Joining} \p{Jt=U} \p{Joining_Type:U} \p{Joining_Type=Non_Joining} \p{Line_Break:AL} \p{Line_Break=Alphabetic} \p{Line_Break:Alphabetic} \p{Lb=AL} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:1.1} \p{Age=1.1} \p{In=1.1}
       \p{Present_In:2.0} \p{In=2.0} \p{Present_In:2.1} \p{In=2.1} \p{Present_In:3.0} \p{In=3.0} \p{Present_In:3.1} \p{In=3.1} \p{Present_In:3.2} \p{In=3.2} \p{Present_In:4.0} \p{In=4.0} \p{Present_In:4.1} \p{In=4.1} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1}
       \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2} \p{Script:Greek} \p{Sc=Grek} \p{Script:Grek} \p{Sentence_Break:UP} \p{Sentence_Break=Upper} \p{Sentence_Break:Upper} \p{SB=UP} \p{Word_Break:ALetter} \p{WB=LE} \p{Word_Break:LE} \p{Word_Break=ALetter}

U+221E ‹∞› \N{ INFINITY }:
    \pS \p{Sm}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Assigned} \p{InMathematicalOperators} \p{Common} \p{Zyyy} \p{Sm} \p{S} \p{Gr_Base} \p{Grapheme_Base} \p{Graph} \p{GrBase} \p{Math} \p{Math_Symbol} \p{Pat_Syn} \p{Pattern_Syntax} \p{PatSyn} \p{Print} \p{Symbol}
    \p{Age:1.1} \p{Bidi_Class:ON} \p{Bidi_Class=Other_Neutral} \p{Bidi_Class:Other_Neutral} \p{Bc=ON} \p{Block:Mathematical_Operators} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Script=Common} \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None} \p{East_Asian_Width:A} \p{East_Asian_Width=Ambiguous} \p{East_Asian_Width:Ambiguous} \p{Ea=A} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Other} \p{GCB=XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:XX}
       \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup} \p{Joining_Type:Non_Joining} \p{Jt=U} \p{Joining_Type:U}
       \p{Joining_Type=Non_Joining} \p{Line_Break:AI} \p{Line_Break=Ambiguous} \p{Line_Break:Ambiguous} \p{Lb=AI} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:1.1} \p{Age=1.1} \p{In=1.1} \p{Present_In:2.0} \p{In=2.0} \p{Present_In:2.1} \p{In=2.1}
       \p{Present_In:3.0} \p{In=3.0} \p{Present_In:3.1} \p{In=3.1} \p{Present_In:3.2} \p{In=3.2} \p{Present_In:4.0} \p{In=4.0} \p{Present_In:4.1} \p{In=4.1} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2} \p{Script:Common} \p{Sc=Zyyy}
       \p{Script:Zyyy} \p{Sentence_Break:Other} \p{SB=XX} \p{Sentence_Break:XX} \p{Sentence_Break=Other} \p{Word_Break:Other} \p{WB=XX} \p{Word_Break:XX} \p{Word_Break=Other}

U+FEFF ‹U+FEFF› \N{ ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE }:
    \pC \p{Cf}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Assigned} \p{InArabicPresentationFormsB} \p{C} \p{Other} \p{Case_Ignorable} \p{CI} \p{Cf} \p{Format} \p{Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded} \p{CWKCF} \p{Common} \p{Zyyy} \p{Default_Ignorable_Code_Point} \p{DI} \p{Graph} \p{Print}
    \p{Age:1.1} \p{Bidi_Class:BN} \p{Bidi_Class=Boundary_Neutral} \p{Bidi_Class:Boundary_Neutral} \p{Bc=BN} \p{Block:Arabic_Presentation_Forms_B} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Script=Common} \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None} \p{East_Asian_Width=Neutral} \p{East_Asian_Width:Neutral} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:CN} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Control} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Control} \p{GCB=CN}
       \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup} \p{Joining_Type:T} \p{Joining_Type=Transparent} \p{Joining_Type:Transparent} \p{Jt=T}
       \p{Line_Break:WJ} \p{Line_Break=Word_Joiner} \p{Line_Break:Word_Joiner} \p{Lb=WJ} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:1.1} \p{Age=1.1} \p{In=1.1} \p{Present_In:2.0} \p{In=2.0} \p{Present_In:2.1} \p{In=2.1} \p{Present_In:3.0}
       \p{In=3.0} \p{Present_In:3.1} \p{In=3.1} \p{Present_In:3.2} \p{In=3.2} \p{Present_In:4.0} \p{In=4.0} \p{Present_In:4.1} \p{In=4.1} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2} \p{Script:Common} \p{Sc=Zyyy} \p{Script:Zyyy}
       \p{Sentence_Break:FO} \p{Sentence_Break=Format} \p{Sentence_Break:Format} \p{SB=FO} \p{Word_Break:FO} \p{Word_Break=Format} \p{Word_Break:Format} \p{WB=FO}

U+3000 ‹U+3000› \N{ IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE }:
    \s \h \pZ \p{Zs}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Assigned} \p{Blank} \p{InCJKSymbolsAndPunctuation} \p{Changes_When_NFKC_Casefolded} \p{CWKCF} \p{Common} \p{Zyyy} \p{Z} \p{Zs} \p{Gr_Base} \p{Grapheme_Base} \p{GrBase} \p{HorizSpace} \p{Print} \p{Separator} \p{Space} \p{Space_Separator} \p{SpacePerl}
       \p{White_Space} \p{WSpace}
    \p{Age:1.1} \p{Bidi_Class:White_Space} \p{Bc=WS} \p{Bidi_Class:WS} \p{Bidi_Class=White_Space} \p{Block:CJK_Symbols_And_Punctuation} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Script=Common} \p{Decomposition_Type:Non_Canon} \p{Decomposition_Type=Non_Canonical} \p{Decomposition_Type:Non_Canonical} \p{Dt=NonCanon} \p{Decomposition_Type:Wide} \p{Dt=Wide} \p{East_Asian_Width:F} \p{East_Asian_Width=Fullwidth}
       \p{East_Asian_Width:Fullwidth} \p{Ea=F} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Other} \p{GCB=XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA}
       \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup} \p{Joining_Type:Non_Joining} \p{Jt=U} \p{Joining_Type:U} \p{Joining_Type=Non_Joining} \p{Line_Break:ID} \p{Line_Break=Ideographic} \p{Line_Break:Ideographic} \p{Lb=ID} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None}
       \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:1.1} \p{Age=1.1} \p{In=1.1} \p{Present_In:2.0} \p{In=2.0} \p{Present_In:2.1} \p{In=2.1} \p{Present_In:3.0} \p{In=3.0} \p{Present_In:3.1} \p{In=3.1} \p{Present_In:3.2} \p{In=3.2} \p{Present_In:4.0} \p{In=4.0} \p{Present_In:4.1}
       \p{In=4.1} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2} \p{Script:Common} \p{Sc=Zyyy} \p{Script:Zyyy} \p{Sentence_Break:Sp} \p{SB=Sp} \p{Word_Break:Other} \p{WB=XX} \p{Word_Break:XX} \p{Word_Break=Other}

U+12345 ‹› \N{ CUNEIFORM SIGN URU TIMES KI }:
    \w} \p{\pL} \p{L_} \p{Lo}
    \p{All} \p{Any} \p{Alnum} \p{Alpha} \p{Alphabetic} \p{Assigned} \p{InCuneiform} \p{Cuneiform} \p{Is_Cuneiform} \p{Xsux} \p{L} \p{Lo} \p{Gr_Base} \p{Grapheme_Base} \p{Graph} \p{GrBase} \p{ID_Continue} \p{IDC} \p{ID_Start} \p{IDS} \p{Letter} \p{L_} \p{Other_Letter} \p{Print}
       \p{Word} \p{XID_Continue} \p{XIDC} \p{XID_Start} \p{XIDS}
    \p{Age:5.0} \p{Bidi_Class:L} \p{Bidi_Class=Left_To_Right} \p{Bidi_Class:Left_To_Right} \p{Bc=L} \p{Block:Cuneiform} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:0} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class=Not_Reordered} \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:Not_Reordered} \p{Ccc=NR}
       \p{Canonical_Combining_Class:NR} \p{Script=Cuneiform} \p{Block=Cuneiform} \p{Decomposition_Type:None} \p{Dt=None} \p{East_Asian_Width=Neutral} \p{East_Asian_Width:Neutral} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:Other} \p{GCB=XX} \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break:XX}
       \p{Grapheme_Cluster_Break=Other} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:NA} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type=Not_Applicable} \p{Hangul_Syllable_Type:Not_Applicable} \p{Hst=NA} \p{Joining_Group:No_Joining_Group} \p{Jg=NoJoiningGroup} \p{Joining_Type:Non_Joining} \p{Jt=U} \p{Joining_Type:U}
       \p{Joining_Type=Non_Joining} \p{Line_Break:AL} \p{Line_Break=Alphabetic} \p{Line_Break:Alphabetic} \p{Lb=AL} \p{Numeric_Type:None} \p{Nt=None} \p{Numeric_Value:NaN} \p{Nv=NaN} \p{Present_In:5.0} \p{In=5.0} \p{Present_In:5.1} \p{In=5.1} \p{Present_In:5.2} \p{In=5.2}
       \p{Script:Cuneiform} \p{Sc=Xsux} \p{Script:Xsux} \p{Sentence_Break:LE} \p{Sentence_Break=OLetter} \p{Sentence_Break:OLetter} \p{SB=LE} \p{Word_Break:ALetter} \p{WB=LE} \p{Word_Break:LE} \p{Word_Break=ALetter}
```

Or, going the other way:

```
$ unichars '\pN' '\D' '\p{Latin}'
 Ⅰ      8544  02160  ROMAN NUMERAL ONE
 Ⅱ      8545  02161  ROMAN NUMERAL TWO
 Ⅲ      8546  02162  ROMAN NUMERAL THREE
 Ⅳ      8547  02163  ROMAN NUMERAL FOUR
 Ⅴ      8548  02164  ROMAN NUMERAL FIVE
 Ⅵ      8549  02165  ROMAN NUMERAL SIX
 Ⅶ      8550  02166  ROMAN NUMERAL SEVEN
 Ⅷ      8551  02167  ROMAN NUMERAL EIGHT
 (etc)

$ unichars -a '\pL' '\p{Greek}' 'NFD ne NFKD' 'NAME =~ /SYMBOL/'
 ϐ       976  3D0  GREEK BETA SYMBOL
 ϑ       977  3D1  GREEK THETA SYMBOL
 ϒ       978  3D2  GREEK UPSILON WITH HOOK SYMBOL
 ϓ       979  3D3  GREEK UPSILON WITH ACUTE AND HOOK SYMBOL
 ϔ       980  3D4  GREEK UPSILON WITH DIAERESIS AND HOOK SYMBOL
 ϕ       981  3D5  GREEK PHI SYMBOL
 ϖ       982  3D6  GREEK PI SYMBOL
 ϰ      1008  3F0  GREEK KAPPA SYMBOL
 ϱ      1009  3F1  GREEK RHO SYMBOL
 ϲ      1010  3F2  GREEK LUNATE SIGMA SYMBOL
 ϴ      1012  3F4  GREEK CAPITAL THETA SYMBOL
 ϵ      1013  3F5  GREEK LUNATE EPSILON SYMBOL
 Ϲ      1017  3F9  GREEK CAPITAL LUNATE SIGMA SYMBOL
```

Oh, and *BNM* means *“Brave New Millennium”*, referring to our modern, post-ASCII world in which characters are more than just seven paltry bits wide. ☺

Answer (score 2):

String.replace() accepts callback function as its second parameter. (Don't know why so many JS tutorials omit this useful feature.) Thus, we can write our own test for word boundaries.

The solution proposed elsewhere, with regexp `/(\W|^)(fancy namé|namé)(\W|$)/ig`, gives false positives in cases of text such as 'naméé'.

```
String.prototype.isWordCharAt = function(i) {
    // should work for European languages and Unicode
    return (this.charAt(i) >= 'A' && this.charAt(i) <= 'Z')
        || (this.charAt(i) >= 'a' && this.charAt(i) <= 'z')
        || (this.charCodeAt(i) >= 0xC0 && this.charCodeAt(i) < 0x2000)
    ;
};

"Namé. Goal: Some Fancy Namé. Namé. Nénamé. Namée. Nénamée. Namé"
.replace(/(Namé|Fancy Namé)/ig, function(
match, part1, /* part2, part3, ... */ offset, fullText) {
  // Keep in mind that the number of arguments changes
  // if the number of capturing parenthesis in regexp changes.
  // We could use 'arguments' pseudo-array instead.
  var len1 = part1.length;
  var leftWordBoundary;
  var rightWordBoundary;

  if (offset === 0) {
    leftWordBoundary = fullText.isWordCharAt(offset);
  }
  else {
    leftWordBoundary = (fullText.isWordCharAt(offset - 1)
      != fullText.isWordCharAt(offset));
  }

  if (offset + len1 == fullText.length) {
    rightWordBoundary = fullText.isWordCharAt(offset + len1 - 1);
  }
  else {
    rightWordBoundary = (fullText.isWordCharAt(offset + len1 - 1)
      != fullText.isWordCharAt(offset + len1));
  }

  if (leftWordBoundary && rightWordBoundary) {
    return '<a href="#">' + part1 + '</a>';
  }
  else {
    return part1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to match "my_word"
you can use negative look behind `?<!` and negative look ahead `?!`

that will check the word is not preceded by a non word character and is not follow by a non word characters
`` new RegExp(`(?<![A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ])my_word(?![A-Za-zÀ-ÖØ-öø-ÿ])`, "gi"); ``

the `-` is for interval in the ascii table.
Here the Ascii table to check it is well what you need 
http://seamons.com/projects/js/ascii_table.html

Answer (score 0):

As other anwsers have already pointed out, the JS regex engine does not consider "é" a word character. Since that's the case, and you want to match if that letter is followed by another non-word character, you can use the [`\B` assertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#boundary-type_assertions) there:

```js
> "Goal: Some Fancy Namé. Awesome.".replace(/\b(Fancy Namé|Namé)\B/i, '<a href="#">$1</a>');
'Goal: Some <a href="#">Fancy Namé</a>. Awesome.'
```

Probably not the best code if you want its intent to be obvious, but it works in this case hehe.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe try using the `\o` or `\x` flags when using your regex.

The end of [this reference for Javascript regular expressions](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmaScript/quickref/regexp_special_characters.html) might help you out.

As to what actual octal/hex values `é` is associated with, I'm not sure.