# Javascript regex to replace word that may contain accent characters

Tags: javascript, regex, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

I've been trying come up with a regex that will replace a word that may or may not contain accent characters.  I've been researching this for the past couple days, but cannot find the information I need to solve my problem.

I had come up with a simple regex that handles words without accent characters great:

```
var re = new RegExp('(?:\\b)hello(?:\\b)', 'gm');
var string = 'hello hello hello world hellos hello';
string.replace(re, "FOO");
```

Result: `FOO FOO FOO world hellos FOO`

The above works as I want.  The problem with the above code, is when the word contains an accent character as the first, or last character in the string.  Example:

```
var re = new RegExp('(?:\\b)helló(?:\\b)', 'gm');
var string = 'helló helló helló world hellós helló';
string.replace(re, "FOO");
```

Result: `helló helló helló world FOOs helló`

Desired result: `FOO FOO FOO world hellós FOO`

From my understanding, the above is occurring because an accented character is interpreted as a boundary.  My attempt at solving the problem (note: the range `[A-zÀ-ÿ]` is what I consider the valid alphabet to construct a word):

```
var re = new RegExp('([^A-zÀ-ÿ]|^)helló([^A-zÀ-ÿ]|$)', 'gm');
var string = 'helló helló helló world hellós helló';
string.replace(re, "$1FOO$2");
```

Result: `FOO helló FOO world hellós FOO`

As you can see, I'm much closer to the desired result.  However, the problem occurs when the word in question appears three or more times in a row.  Please note the second occurrence of `helló` was ignored.  I believe that's because the whitespace preceding it was already matched by the first occurence of `helló`.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to achieve `FOO FOO FOO world hellós FOO`?

Comment: Very likely a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436824/matching-accented-characters-with-javascript-regexes but I am not using the hamer until confirmed

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the requirements are for matching the word? Is it replaced for any instance anywhere within the string or at a specific place. So instead of that regex why not `helló\B`?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a little complex, but has been answered in the following as to why you are struggling on this issue: [Why can't I use accented characters next to a word boundary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449779/why-cant-i-use-accented-characters-next-to-a-word-boundary)

However, given the lack of good unicode support in Javascript, especially before ECMAScript 6 (I've had this issue myself in the past). I have found that it is often better to use a third party library with better unicode support such as: http://xregexp.com/

This also eliminates some of the variances in support from older browsers.