# How to do a string.match condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to store 21 char in an array from a string.
my problem is when I'm writing a paragraph it cuts the word like this.

```js
    let string = "This is a new paragraphe that i'm writing to you" //  48 chars and 10 words
    let lines = string.match(/.{1,21}/g)
    console.log(lines) //  ["This is a new paragra", "phe that i'm writing ", "to you"]
```

I want it to look like this ["This is a new" , "paragraphe that i'm" , "writing to you"]
and don't cut the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\b` anchors to define word boundaries, and you are set:

```js
let string = "This is a new paragraphe that i'm writing to you";

let lines = string
  .match(/\b.{1,21}\b/g)
  .map(line => line.trim());
  
console.log(lines);
```

Comment: when i'm trying something like this.
string= "Le mot le plus long de la langue française Anti Consituionnellement"

I get ["Le mot le plus long", "de la langue franç", "aise est", "Anti", "Consituionnellement"]

it's in french and like you see it cut my word

Comment: @EyTa -- please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449779/why-cant-i-use-accented-characters-next-to-a-word-boundary). This is a limitation of JavaScript.