# Error while tokenizing Bangla Number(Digits) as Number token using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, jison

I'm new to Jison and I want to tokenize Bangla Digits **০-৯** as numbers. I've tried the regex below but it's not working with it:
Regular Expression: **(^[\u09E6-\u09EF])+("."[\u09E6-\u09EF])\b**

On testing **৭+১** It showing expected... 'NUMBER' GOT 'Invalid' 
Expected result : NUMBER '+' NUMBER

Please help me out!! ❤️

Comment: please post some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

The problem is the `\b` word boundary assertion. For some reason, javascript's regular expression engine specification does not consider Bangla digits to be word characters. [For `\w` and `\b`, only ascii letters and digits count as word characters.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2449892/1566221)

Consequently, a Bangla digit followed by a plus sign (which is certainly not a word character) is not considered a word boundary, and thus doesn't match the assertion.

If you just drop the `\b`, it should work (although I would also drop the `^`: Jison patterns are always anchored, so there's no need to insist).